# How do I send data in a url to test a php file?

Tags: php, android

I am trying to see what is wrong with a php script a wrote. The script is getting information from an android application and then using that data to search a table and send information back. The client side is written like this:

```
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("num1", num1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("num2", num2));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("num3", num3));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("num4", num4));


    InputStream is = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.0.4/xampp/phpfile.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
```

How do I format the url in a browser if I want to execute the same script passing num1, num2, num3 and num4 in the same way?

Comment: You can use the curl command line tool. Try to give a look here [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/149329/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-the-curl-command-line-tool

Comment: `http://10.0.0.4/xampp/phpfile.php?num1=num1&num2=num2&num3=num3&num4=num4` - but this probably won't work, since the code above uses POST and passing data in the URL is GET. You need something like [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) for Firefox or any one of a million other similar tools if you want to do it in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using POST methos, as I can see, you can't call it from a browser url.
You can write a simple html file, with a form in it, wich uses post method, and then submit that.
Or modify the server side php file, and instead of using $_POST[] variables use $_REQUEST[] variables, wich accept both GET and POST method calls.
In this case:
http://10.0.0.4/xampp/phpfile.php?num1=num1&num2=num2...
should work fine.

Comment: ahh, ok. so if I want to print the result in my browser, what would I use instead of: print(json_encode($output));

Comment: echo $_REQUEST['name_parameter']; http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/php/php_p2.php

Answer (score 2):

use http://hurl.it/ to test POST request from your browser...

Comment: You can find tools like hurl.it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12637452/363573)